# Not able to connect to local elasticsearch process from docker container

Tags: python, docker, elasticsearch

**EDIT**

I think what is going on is that localhost inside the docker process refers to the container's own localhost, not my system's localhost. So how do I ensure that when the application running the container tries to connect to the container's localhost:9200, it actually connects to my system's localhost:9200?

When I visit localhost:9200, my ES application seems to be running. It looks like this in chrome:

```
{
  "name" : "H1YDvcg",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch_jwan",
  "cluster_uuid" : "aAorzRYTQPOI0j_OgMGKpA",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "6.8.1",
    "build_flavor" : "oss",
    "build_type" : "tar",
    "build_hash" : "1fad4e1",
    "build_date" : "2019-06-18T13:16:52.517138Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "7.7.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "5.6.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "5.0.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

I am running ES in a terminal window and it works after I run the command `elasticsearch`.

I am running a docker container with this command:

```
docker run -e DATALOADER_QUEUE='<some aws SQS queue name'\
             -e ES_HOST='localhost'\
             -e ES_PORT='9200'\
             -e AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID='<somekey>'\
             -e AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY='<somekey>'\
             -e AWS_DEFAULT_REGION='us-west-2'\
             <application name>
```

and I get this error:

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=9200): Max retries exceeded with url: /person/_search (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f36e4189c90>
```

Anyone know what is going on? I don't understand why it cannot connect to ES even though ti seems to be running on localhost:9200.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach)

Answer (score 3):

Solution was to use `host.docker.internal` in ES host setup.

I just used `es_client = Elasticsearch(host=_es_host,` where es_host = `host.docker.internal` and made sure to use http while local instead of https.

Answer (score 1):

Elasticsearch is running on your host at port `9200` and the application which want to access elasticsearch is running inside container.

The docker container by default runs in [bridge](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/) networking mode, in which host and container network are different. Hence localhost inside container is not the same as on host.

Here you can do two things:

- In your application code try to access elasticsearch using `private/public-ip:9200`

OR

- Run docker container in [host](https://docs.docker.com/network/host/) networking mode, so that localhost inside container is same as that on host. Because in this mode container uses network of host.

```
docker run -e DATALOADER_QUEUE='<some aws SQS queue name'\
             -e ES_HOST='localhost'\
             -e ES_PORT='9200'\
             -e AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID='<somekey>'\
             -e AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY='<somekey>'\
             -e AWS_DEFAULT_REGION='us-west-2'\
             --net=host \
             <application name>
```

**NOTE:** `--net=host` option will tell docker container to use host networking mode.

Comment: I tried this but then my requests to aws then seem to be to host

Comment: @Jwan622 that will definitely happen since you want localhost inside container to be same as inside host.

Comment: Or changing application code to point to machine ip will be good option.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind a host port to docker port using the -p option docker command. So in your below docker command, you can add one more line for binding the host 9200 port to docker 9200 port. notice I have added `-p 9200:9200` and same is explained nicely in point 3 [this](http://containertutorials.com/network/basic_network.html) doc

```
docker run -p 9200:9200 -e DATALOADER_QUEUE='<some aws SQS queue name'\
             -e ES_HOST='localhost'\
             -e ES_PORT='9200'\
             -e AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID='<somekey>'\
             -e AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY='<somekey>'\
             -e AWS_DEFAULT_REGION='us-west-2'\
             <application name>
```

Comment: the -e flag should be behind the -p 9200:9200 right?

Comment: So I treid this again and it didn't work. Basically this should fix what I think is the problem: that my docker application is making requests to localhost:9200 but it's making them to the localhost inside the container and not the host's localhost right? For some reason this didn't work.

Comment: The problem with this answer is `-p` option will forward request coming at 9200 port on host to 9200 port inside container. But what you want is other way round. From container 9200 port to -> host 9200 port.

Comment: @Jwan622 That's what I tried to answer in my post. :)

Comment: Go through the host and bridge networking documentation that I provided in my answer, It will help you to understand the docker networking and get clear idea of my answer.